# Raven DB - Optimal document size

Tags: ravendb, nosql

I found this [link](https://ayende.com/blog/156865/ravendb-net-memory-management-and-variable-size-obese-documents) where RavenDB author explains that, in spite of the fact that Raven DB has a huge document size limit (around 2 GB), it is unhealthy to manage too big files (among other reasons, it makes the indexing process too slow). What is the maximum size that is still "healthy" for the system? If it is not documented, is there a best way to determine this size somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Up to a few MB, that is fine. Beyond a few MB, the sending and retrieving of documents become awkward.

Comment: I would like to ask for some clarification on when data is actually sent over the network.  Would I be correct in thinking a document load, is a purely server side operation, and the only time data is transferred over the network is when the view is loaded with the viewmodel?

Comment: No, `Load` actually send the data over the network, from then, all operations are purely local on the data that was sent to the app

Comment: Ok thanks. Reason I ask is our current application uses 1 document  to hold all data which includes many lists.  There is a chance some documents will own a list of many thousands, so this is going to be a big problem if it has to transfer that list over the network every time a load is called.  It looks like a complete redesign is therefore necessary.

Comment: That might be a good idea. You _can_ do projections for some part of it, but this doesn't look like a cohesive document design